# How to use javaxt on mac?

Tags: java

i am using jdk1.6 and the following code is working properly on windows,but i need to run it 
mac also But it is not running on mac, can anyone told me.
how to run it on mac?

```
      javaxt.io.File file1=new javaxt.io.File(fname);
      Date d1=file1.getLastAccessTime();      
      System.out.println("LastAccessed Date:"+d1);
      Date d2=file1.getCreationTime();
      System.out.println("Creation time of file"+d2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest release of javaxt-core, version 1.5.6, includes a fix for Mac OS X. Here's the website: 
http://www.javaxt.com